# What TV show is this?

Tags: word, knowledge

> Each of these clues is a river. When you figure out all the rivers you'll be able to know what TV show this is.
>
> 1. Failed to cross
> 2. Gold, Solitaire, Island
> 3. Three times I'm delayed yet I still make the journey
> 4. I once made a trek through New Granada
> 5. Look at
> 6. CCLMTV
> 7. Beginning from a great state of red
> 8. I feed a tiger
> 9. Native American Chief
> 10. Oy rats have learned to adapt
> 11. From black, red, and gold to black

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on all the other answers:

1. Failed to cross

   > Rubicon (Caesar crossing several times the Rubicon)
2. Gold, Solitaire, Island

   > Yukon (Klondike gold rush)
3. Three times I'm delayed yet I still make the journey

   > Yangtzee Kiang
4. I once made a trek through New Granada

   > Orinoco
5. Look at

   > Gander (means a goose or a glance i.e. look at).
6. CCLMTV

   > Mekong (crossing the countries with this initials)
7. Beginning from a great state of red

   > Rio Grande - "great river" originating in Colorado ("colored red")
8. I feed a tiger

   > Ganges (flows into the Bay of Bengal - Bengal tiger)
9. Native American Chief

   > Shenandoah (not sure but it might be an anglicised version of a Native American name)
10. Oy rats have learned to adapt

    > Volga river Which the Oirat name for means adaptation river
11. From black, red, and gold to black

    > Danube

And the show is

> Star Trek: Deep Space 9
>  Danube is a class of shuttlecraft and the rivers are all names of shuttlecrafts.

Credit goes to @DanielSchepler, @NetJohn, @CJDennis, @CharlesTrotter, @Veskah, @DaveP

Comment: Close... I think i'll modify the clue slightly to make it a bit more exacting

Comment: #7 and #10 are flipped

Comment: @Buildstarted I can swap them but this will void the reasoning.

Comment: That's the right reasoning now :)

Comment: Wait - that's the right reasoning for number 7?

Comment: @Chris My bad, I just fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

3. Three times I'm delayed yet I still make the journey

> Mississippi?  ("Three times I'm delayed" -> the three sets of double letters, "I still make the journey" maybe referring to its role in *Huckleberry Finn*?)

4. I once made a trek through New Granada.

> Orinoco?  It's a major river of present-day Colombia, and for wordplay, it looks like "I once" shares a lot of letters with it.

7. Beginning from a state of red

> Makes me think of the Missouri River which starts in Montana, which voted for Trump - though I'm not at all sure of this one.

9. Native American Chief

> Probably a stretch, but - Ganges?  (Chief river of India.)

10. Oy rats have learned to adapt

> Another stretch - rot13 "oy rats" and you get "bl engf".  "Adapt" it by changing F to A and anagramming, and you get Bengal?  (Though looking it up on Wikipedia gives the official name as Hooghly River...)

11. From black, red, and gold to black

> Guessing this is the Danube - which flows from Germany (with the black, red and gold flag, as Veskah already observed) to the Black Sea.

Comment: 4, 11 are correct :)

Answer (score 2):

2. Gold, Solitaire, Island

> Klondike (not sure on the Island part)

Comment: Very close... :)

Answer (score 2):

6. CCLMTV

> Mekong - flows through China (C), Cambodia (C), Laos (L), Malaysia (M), Taiwan (T) and Vietnam (V)

7. Beginning from a great state of red

> Rio Grande - "great river" originating in Colorado ("colored red")

8. I feed a tiger

> Ganges - flows into the Bay of Bengal

11. From black, red, and gold to black

> Danube - begins in Germany (German flag is black, red, and gold) and empties into the Black Sea

Comment: 6, 8, 11 are all correct

Comment: Can't flow through Taiwan, it's an island.  Thailand, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

The rivers are:

1. Failed to cross

   > ?
2. Gold, Solitaire, Island

   > ?
3. Three times I'm delayed yet I still make the journey

   > Yangtzee Kiang
4. I once made a trek through New Granada

   > Orinoco
5. Look at

   > ?
6. CCLMTV

   > Mekong
7. Beginning from a great state of red

   > ?
8. I feed a tiger

   > Ganges
9. Native American Chief

   > ?
10. Oy rats have learned to adapt

    > ?
11. From black, red, and gold to black

    > Danube

And the show is

> Star Trek: Deep Space 9
>
>  The rivers are all names of shuttlecraft.

Answer (score 0):

3. Three times I'm delayed yet I still make the journey

> Yangtze River? It's blocked by the Three Gorges Dam and makes it to the East China Sea

8. I feed a tiger

> Tigris is Greek for Tiger and I don't really see a river tributary for it.

11. From black, red, and gold to black

> The Rhine? Black, Red and Gold seems to be Germany and I guess you can say the North sea is black but that doesn't seem very good.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling!

Comment: #3 is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

2

> gander

7

> Volga flowing through Russia 1)rubicon the river that ceaser crossed

Answer (score 0):

10. Oy rats have learned to adapt

> Volga River - Which the Oirat name for means adaptation river

A long shot at 5. Look at

> River Soar - if you look at it you saw(Soar) it

Answer (score -1):

1 Failed to cross

> Rubicon

2 Gold, Solitaire, Island

> Yukon

3 Three times I'm delayed yet I still make the journey

> Yangtze

4 I once made a trek through New Granada

> Orinoco

5 Look at

> Gander

6 CCLMTV

> Mekong

7 Beginning from a great state of red

> Volga

8 I feed a tiger

> Ganges

9 Native American Chief

> Shenandoah

10 Oy rats have learned to adapt

> Rio Grande

11 From black, red, and gold to black

> Danube

And the show is:

> Star Trek: Deep Space 9. Runabouts are all named after rivers. However, the Yellowstone comes from an episode of Star Trek: Voyager.

Comment: Hello and welcome to PSE. Because most of the answers were already published, it is only polite to credit the authors of the previous answers. Otherwise this will be a duplicated answer which doesn't add value to the topic.

Comment: @rhsquared I didn't read any other answers. I recognized a few of them, got the TV show, and realized the rest. When I have time, I can look at the previous answers and try to determine who had them first. I believe this is the first answer to provide a complete (and likely correct) solution, though.

Comment: (Independent work doesn't redeem a duplicative answer; it's still duplicative. You should always look at existing answers before providing one of your own, to ensure you are not just adding a duplicate. There is value in a collected-answers post, as [rhsquared did here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/63670), but credit should always be given to the posters who got there first.  If there is no part of the answer that wasn't already provided elsewhere, and no credit is given to the first providers of the answer, a collected answer that isn't CW looks suspiciously like a rep grab.)

Comment: Also, it'd be best to include some sort of explanation as to how each answer fits each clue, instead of just giving the end result :)